# elementary question concerning definition of sifted colimit

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

I am reading a proof (in *Algebraic Theories* by Adamek et al, Theorem 2.15) for the fact that sifted categories $\mathcal{D}$ are precisely those for which the diagonal functor $\Delta : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{D} \times \mathcal{D}$ is final. By definition, $\mathcal{D}$ is sifted iff for every finite discrete category $I$ and every diagram

$$D : \mathcal{D} \times I \to Set$$

the canonical morphism

$$ colim_\mathcal{D}\big(\prod_ID(d,i)\big) \to \prod_I(colim_\mathcal{D} D(d,i)$$
is an isomorphism. Now according to the proof, in the case that $I$ is the two-element set this

> ...means that for every pair $D, D':\mathcal{D} \to Set$ of diagrams, the colimit of the diagram 
>   $$ D \times D' : \mathcal{D} \times \mathcal{D} \to Set, \qquad (d,d') \mapsto Dd \times D'd'$$
>   is canonically isomorphic to $colimD \times colimD'$.

[This passage is taken from Remark 2.2.2 of the cited book.]

I interpret the left hand side in the above definition as follows: consider the diagram $D_1 : \mathcal{D} \to [I, Set]$ obtained from $D$ by adjunction, then take the (tip of the) product of the diagram $D_1(d)$ for each $d \in \mathcal{D}$; this gives a functor $\mathcal{D} \to Set $ of which we can now take the colimit. Since products can be formed componentwise in functor categories, in the case $I = 2$ we get the diagram
$$ \mathcal{D} \to Set ,\qquad  d \mapsto Dd \times D'd$$

Am I missing something here or is this really a mistake? The latter seems very improbable to me as the idea of the whole proof would (as far as I can see) not work in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are connecting two statements that aren't (immediately) connected.  The part in your block quote is simply true in $\mathbf{Set}$ for all (small enough) categories $\mathcal{D}$, not just sifted ones.  It's a simple corollary of the fact that $-\times S$ is a left adjoint (and thus cocontinuous) for any set $S$.

Explicitly, using coend notation for the colimits (though they are just colimits), we have, going right to left from the statement:
$$\left(\int^{c\in\mathcal{C}}F(c)\right)\times\left(\int^{d\in\mathcal{D}}G(d)\right) \cong \int^{c\in\mathcal{C}}\int^{d\in\mathcal{D}}F(c)\times G(d) \cong \int^{(c,d)\in\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D}}F(c)\times G(d)$$

Then the question is, when $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{D}$: "does 'pulling back' along $\Delta : \mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{D}\times\mathcal{D}$ preserve this colimit?"  This is exactly the question: "is $\Delta$ final?"  If $\mathcal{D}$ is sifted, then the answer is "yes" because the far left term is isomorphic to $\int^{d\in\mathcal{D}}F(d)\times G(d)$ by siftedness.  If $\Delta$ is final, we get $\mathcal{D}$ is sifted by recursively applying the above isomorphism and finality of $\Delta$.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand how the proof is meant. The way they formulate it in the book is not quite correct though, or at least very misleading.

Comment: Why do you bring up coends? You could just as well use the notation $\varinjlim_\mathcal{C} \varinjlim_\mathcal{D}$ and $\varinjlim_{\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{D}}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin I just used the notation because I prefer it (though it does have some issues.)  (I also prefer the *concept* and calculational fluidity of (co)ends to (conical) (co)limits, but that's a different story, and I agree doesn't make a big impact here.)

Comment: One benefit of coend notation in this case, though, is it makes cocontinuity of $\times$ look like a form of bilinearity which is a useful guide.  The notation is suggestive in other ways (sometimes misleadingly, but not in this case.)